# How to generate a nested block for Terraform resource from JSON file for AWS QuickSight resource

Tags: terraform, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to build Terraform `aws_quicksight_analysis` resource.
The idea is to read the QuickSight Analysis definition using AWS SDK and save it to a JSON file, for example, from dev env.
Then read JSON and create QuickSight Analysis using Terraform in another env, like `test`.

The difficulties I met were reading JSON and assigning to block in Terraform resource. Since defining each block is quite a difficult task since this resource contains dozens of them, maybe there is some standard way or workaround for doing it?

The working approach:

```
resource "aws_quicksight_analysis" "example" {
  analysis_id = "example-id"
  name        = "example-name"
  definition {
    data_set_identifiers_declarations {
      data_set_arn = "arn:..."
      identifier   = "Sales Pipeline"
    }
    sheets {
      name     = "Sheet 1"
      sheet_id = "sheet-1"
      visuals {
        line_chart_visual {
          visual_id = "LineChart"
          title {
            format_text {
              plain_text = "Historical  opportunity pipeline"
            }
          }
          chart_configuration {
            field_wells {
              line_chart_aggregated_field_wells {
                category {
                  date_dimension_field {
                    field_id = "FieldId2"
                    column {
                      data_set_identifier = "Sales Pipeline"
                      column_name         = "Date"
                    }
                    hierarchy_id = "FieldId2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          column_hierarchies {
            date_time_hierarchy {
              hierarchy_id = "FieldId2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      layouts {
        configuration {
          grid_layout {
            elements {
              element_id   = "LineChart"
              element_type = "VISUAL"
              column_index = 0
              column_span  = 12
              row_index    = 0
              row_span     = 4
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So resource `aws_quicksight_analysis` consists of a lot of nested blocks

The idea is to read `definition` from JSON something like this:

```
resource "aws_quicksight_analysis" "analysis_2" {
  analysis_id = "example-id-1"
  name        = "example-name-1"
  definition = jsondecode(data.local_file.input_template.content)
}
```

But I got the error:

```
An argument named "definition" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "definition"?
```

Do you have an idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic blocks for this:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

You could then make a variable settings or use a JSON like you proposed.

```
resource "aws_quicksight_analysis" "analysis_2" {
  analysis_id = "example-id-1"
  name        = "example-name-1"
  dynamic "definition" {
     for_each = var.settings
     content {
         // here you can build the block, it supports nested dynamic blocks as well
     }
  }
}
```

Be aware that using dynamic blocks extensively can make your Terraform code hard to read. If you find you need to use it a lot might make a switch to Terragrunt and work with an external module instead so the repeated code centralises in that module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that resource `aws_quicksight_analysis` consists of dozens of nested blocks, so I need to define each block, but the idea is to define everything from JSON.

Comment: With pure Terraform I do not think this is possible. Because you would need to create the nested dynamic blocks and then for_each the json. This kind of defeats the purpose as you must still make the structure of the blocks. However Terragrunt has a solution for this that allows you to generate Terraform code: https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#generate

Comment: Hi There @Oleksandr Yarushevskyi, was any solution agreed upon? I have a similar case as well